# python astype and reshape to c# conversion

Tags: c#, python, converters

I'm creating a program in c# that involves reshaping and converting bytearrays, but I can't find any solution for the following line of code, which is written in python:

```
mybytearray.astype('uint16').reshape(h, l, w)
```

Can someone help me with this conversion, as it is a crucial piece of code for my program to work!

Kind regards,
QuickScoP3s

Answer (score 0):

`astype` in Python does type conversion. To convert your byte array into an unsigner 16-bit integer in C#, try this:

```
ushort myVal = BitConverter.ToUInt16( mybytearray, 0 )
```

This reads the first two bytes from your array and converts them into an unsigner 16-bit integer. `myVal` will contain the value.

Comment: thank you, but how can I convert it further into a 3-dimensional array? That's what the reshape part does

Comment: @QuickScoP3s - How are you trying to reshape it? In other words, can you give an example of input and expected output?